# The meaning of "влекомый"

Tags: лексикон, глаголы

Is it possible to use "влекомый" as a passive participle of the verb "влечь" in meaning "to cause"? I can only think of examples where it is used in meaning "to carry" or "to attract":

> карета, влекомая лошадьми - a coach carried by horses
>   человек, влекомый интересом к искусству ~ a man attracted to art

However, phrases like "наказание, влекомое преступлением" sound wrong to me.

My question is: do such phrases seem incorrect to other native speakers? If yes, is there a reason or a rule why the verb "влечь"-"to cause" cannot be used in the form of a passive participle?

Comment: Looks perfectly OK for me except the word is bit old-fashioned.

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard this word spoken in real life. It seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Word *влекомый*, while produced from *влечь*, is normally used to describe a (usually) slow pulling of something or someone by something or someone else, usually with the will or agreement of the person or object being pulled, and often in a poetic speech, with some element of mystery in it, for example

> он шел по тропинке, влекомый памятью о прошлом
>   кибитка катилась вперед, влекомая тихим шагом лошади

Using word *влекомый* as a derivative of *влечь* in meaning *to carry* is grammatically and technically correct; however it is not used often.  It is interesting to note that using its active counterparts *влекущий* и *повлекший* is perfectly fine in such cases:

> преступление, влекущее наказание
>   халатность, повлекшая крупный ущерб

Answer (score 3):

As for

> phrases like "наказание, влекомое преступлением"

this is indeed a construction which, though most probably will be understandable by any native speaker, is not used in Russian, whether colloquial or bookish.

"Влекомый" has a slightest hint on causation in sentences like:

> Скрудж подошел к окну и, влекомый любопытством, выглянул наружу.

One can rephrase: "Скрудж выглянул наружу, потому что ему было любопытно".

or

> И вот наш принц, пройдя огонь и воду, Находит апельсины через годы, Влекомый жаждой разрезает плод.

You can claim that prince cuts the oranges, because he is thirsty.

So, rule of thumb is following here: when you can answer on "why" question, you can use "влекомый", any other use for causation in this very form (as for related forms, see @Aleks G's answer) is highly disputable.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are correct, but it would be better to say:

> человек, увлечённый искусством

---

> наказание, влекомое преступлением

As to me, this phrase sounds correct, but unnatural:

I'd rather use:

> преступление, `влекущее` наказание
>
> преступление, `повлекшее` наказание
>
> наказание, `явившееся следствием` преступления
>
> наказание, `обусловленное` преступлением

Answer (score 1):

"влекомый" чем-то материальным всё же стилистическая ошибка, хотя и относительно лёгкая.
"Влекомым" можно быть чувством, стремлением. Духовной категорией.

Comment: Ну отчего ж всегда ошибка, иногда это осознанное стилистическое смешение - влекомый пончиками, например)

Answer (score 1):

Хотя техническое построение фразы "наказание, влекомое за преступлением" верно, обычно употребляют иную конструкцию: "преступление, влекущее наказание". 
Почему так? Во втором предложении: "человек, влекомый интересом к искусству" пожалуй, нагляднее всего раскрывается смысл употребления слова "влекомый". Объектом выступает в этом предложении "искусство", оно воздействует на субъект (человека) и вызывает влечение. Объектом может выступать, как правило, идея, понятие, человек или даже неодушевленные предметы или животные, в зависимости от контекста. Но когда слово "влекомый" употребляют в контексте с неодушевленными предметами, то фраза приобретает некоторый метафорический подтекст. Например, в первом предложении: "карета, влекомая лошадью", автор пытается изобразить, что в этом процессе передвижения кареты есть нечто волшебное, поэтому они применяет слово "влекомый", который чаще употребляется в разговорах об идеях и понятиях, которые вызывают влечение. 
Если вернутся к предложению: "наказание, влекомое за преступлением", то в нем невозможно даже метафорически, что понятие "наказание" будет испытывать чувство влечения к понятию "преступление". Здесь "влекомое" может выступать только в роли не очень удачного синонима фразы "следующее за", то есть: "наказание, следующее за преступлением".
Попробую перевести на английский.

---

Though your example: "преступление, влекомое наказанием" technically correct, usually we use another phrase: "преступление, влекущее наказание".
Why so? Perhaps in the second sentence: "человек, влекомый интересом к искусству" the meaning of the word "влекомый" is best revealed. "Искусство" is an object, it affects on subject (человек) and causes affection. Object can be an idea, conception, human or even inanimated thing or animal according to context. But when we use "влекомый" in context of inanimated things, the phrase takes on a metaphorical sense. For example, in the first sentence: "карета, влекомая лошадью", author tried to show that in the process of coach's moving was something magic. That's why he used the word "влекомый", which is usually used in talks about ideas and conceptions, which causes affection, causes sympathy or inspiration.
When we read the sentence: "наказание, влекомое за преступлением" we can't imagine, that even metaphorically "наказание" may have the feeling of attraction of "преступление". In this sentence the word "влекомое" may be used as not very good synonym of "следующее за": "наказание, следующее за преступлением".

Comment: It's a very unusual point of view!

Comment: *наказание, влекомое за преступлением* is ungrammatical. It's either *наказание, влекомое преступлением*, or obsolete (but used in the past) *наказание, влекомое преступлением за собой*.

Comment: >It's a very unusual point of view!  It's pity, that you didn't expain why.  @Quassnoi, I didn't say anything about phrases: "наказание, влекомое за преступлением", "наказание, влекомое преступлением за собой". But I agree with you, that these phrases are incorrect.

Comment: *Хотя техническое построение фразы "наказание, влекомое за преступлением" верно* - that is how your post begins.

Comment: Oh yes. There should be: "Хотя техническое построение фразы "наказание, влекомое  преступлением" " I didn't try to explain another phrase, I messed up :)

Answer (score 0):

It means *one who is being led, pulled, attracted, etc.*

And its use in the above examples seems perfectly correct.

Comment: I don't think you're actually answering the question asked...

Answer (score 0):

The meaning "to cause" used to belong to the phrase «влечь за собой»: «Преступление влечет за собой наказание». [In the Russian corpus, the first use without "за собой" is in 1975](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=26251&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%EB%E5%F7%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%ED%E0%EA%E0%E7%E0%ED%E8%E5&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags2=&m3=). Apparently we're not used to using «влекомый» with this freshly discovered meaning yet.

«Наказание, влекомое за собой преступлением» sounds unwieldy but could - says my linguistic intuition - appear in some legal or philosophical text, where the unwieldier the language the higher the score.

---

Ok, extra analysis:

The first, main, meaning of «влечь» - *to drag* - is spatial: X drags Y, *making Y to follow itself* (i.e. move behind it in space).

The second, originally figurative, meaning - *to cause* - is temporal, based on a metaphorical reinterpretation of time as space: X cases Y, *making Y to follow itself* (i.e. happen after it in time).

Now, **«тележка, влекомая лошадкой»** uses present tense, placing both a horsy and a cart in the same moment: right now the car is being dragged by the horse.

**«Наказание, влекомое преступлением»** attempts to do the same - to place crime and punishment in the same, present, moment. But that's not how causality works, at least on macro level, so our brain/intuition resists.

To prove this, I would need to construct a phrase in such a way that there is a sense of temporal sequence in it, using passive participle in future or past tense. But when I try to conjugate «влекомый» to either it declines.

---

In fact, your second example displays yet another shade of meaning - *to attract*: **«магнит влечёт железяки / железяки, влекомые магнитом»** (unusual for modern language but cf. [«Известно любопытным естеств взыскателем есть, что магнит камень силу свою, которою влеком есть к железу, окормляет, силою железа себе обложеннаго»](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=10&spp=50&spd=10&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_created&lang=ru&parent=0&level=0&lex1=%E2%EB%E5%F7%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent=0&level=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&docid=49070&sid=48)), **«запах влечёт мух / мухи, влекомые запахом»** (sounds more natural) and **«интерес к искусству влечёт человека / человек, влекомый интересом к искусству»**. This meaning is again figurative, based on reinterpretation of the described phenomena as if there was some sort of virtual rope with which magnets, smells and interest in arts drag correspondingly iron particles, flies and men. Since attraction happens with agent and patient both being present, the phenomena are again compatible with present tense participle.

Comment: Думаю, что вполне возможны такие примеры с глаголом "влечь", в которых не используется "за собой" и которые тем не менее значат "to cause"

Comment: Да, возможны, начиная с 1975 находится много. Глагол уже отбросил от себя «за собой» за избыточностью, а причастие, похоже, ещё нет.